# How to best debug a layer which is not visible

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I'm having a Kinetic.Layer which I don't understand why it doesn't show. And I wonder if there is a (easy) way to debug or see why it won't show.

If I use a Kinetic.Group it is shown, so I'm troubled what's the difference between those to and how to solve it.

Strange thing is that just changing from a Group to a Layer with the exact same code make it disappears.

Here is the code:

```
 createTickerGroup: function (index) {
    var symbolGroup = new Kinetic.Layer({
        opacity: 0.8,
        clearBeforeDraw: true
    });
    var fontSize = Math.floor(this.layer.getHeight() * 0.8);
    var textConfig = {
        text: "text " + index,
        align: "left",
        fontSize: fontSize,
        fontFamily: "TSTARMedium",
        textFill: "#000000",
        clearBeforeDraw: true
    };

    var symbolText = new Kinetic.Text(textConfig);
    symbolText.setName("@nm");
    var pcText = new Kinetic.Text(textConfig);
    pcText.setName("@pc");
    var chText = new Kinetic.Text(textConfig);
    chText.setName("@ch");
    var chpText = new Kinetic.Text(textConfig);
    chpText.setName("@chp");
    var crText = new Kinetic.Text(textConfig);
    crText.setName("@cr");

    symbolGroup.add(symbolText);
    symbolGroup.add(pcText);
    symbolGroup.add(chText);
    symbolGroup.add(chpText);
    symbolGroup.add(crText);

    return symbolGroup;
}
```

Comment: Try posting your code so that error can be identified, showing layer is very basic step in KineticJS so clearly there is some error in the way you are trying to use it.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you do

```
 layer.add(group);
```

and if you already are,

```
 layer.draw();
```

to redraw the layer. also remove

```
    opacity: 0.8,
    clearBeforeDraw: true
```

as attributes of the layer.